# How to create collection in Cloud Firestore from Javascript?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

When user creates account in my angular app, my app creates user account (using Firebase API) with email and password. But also I want to create new collection to hold more data like name, surname...

Each collection's name will have uid.
But I don't know how to force it? 
`db.createCollection('abcXdefX')` doesn't exist. 
I've no idea what to do. Please, help.

Answer (score 8):

**You cannot create empty collection, you have to create document inside.**
[data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

```
function writeUserData(userId, name, email, imageUrl) {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        username: name,
        email: email,
        profile_picture : imageUrl
      });
    }
```

You can get user id in this way

```
var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
```

For cloud firestore

```
db.doc(userId + '/data').set({
  name: name,
  email: email
});
```

[firebase doc - read&write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to have a "user" collection. Name of the collection is userId.

Comment: So change the path to this: `firebase.database().ref(userId)`

Comment: You can't create empty collection so you need to create some doc e.g `db.collection(userId).doc("data").set({
    name: "username"
})`

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to create a collection within a document and the accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did:

```js
db
    .collection("coll1")
    .doc("doc1")
    .collection("newCollectionName")
    .doc("newDocName")
    .set(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Firestore, when you add a document to a non-existent collection, the collection gets created without needing to specifically create it.  For example,

`firebase.firestore().collection("new-coll").add({"Hello":"World"})`

creates the collection `new-coll` if it does not exist and adds the document `{"Hello": "World"}` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a document inside the collection. You don't have to create a different collection every time.

```js
db.collection("users").doc("userid").set({
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password', 
    email: 'email', 
    age: 'age' 
})
```