# Flutter firestore add collection and data in document

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add data and collection both I am trying like this

```
  Future<void> createRoom(collection, docid, data) async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collection)
        .doc()
        .set(data)
        .collection('messages');
  }
```

But its showing error `The method 'collection' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to set a document in a sub-collection then first create a DocumentReference to that collection and then use `set()`:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection(collection)
  .doc("doc_id")
  .collection('messages')
  .doc("msg_id")
  .set(data)
```

Do note that you should pass document ID in `doc()` else it'll generate a random ID every time instead updating existing one.

---

> I want to add data and collection both

You don't need to create a collection explicitly if you are not adding a document yet. It'll be created at the time you add first document in collection. So try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
Future<void> createRoom(collection, docid, data) async {
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(collection)
    .doc("doc_Id")
    .set(data);

  // simply add a document in messages sub-collection when needed.
}
```

Also checkout: [How to create collection in Cloud Firestore from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47871288/13130697)